# Jquery Mobile navigations using different panels, breaks css

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile, navbar

I have a problem which I can't clearly consider to be a *navigation* problem or *dynamic display* of content problem. Firstly, I am using a single html page which hosts multiple pages where I have two navbars for each page: a header and a footer.

The first page display contents which are dynamically fetched from php at the backend as JSON object using *getJSON()*. The content are displayed as children of three **collapsible items** using the html() function of these collapsible items. The content are filled in **H1** and two **lists** children tags of the collapsible items respectively.

My upper navbar has three entries **(page1, page2, page3)**. When I navigate from **page1** to **page2**, then click **page1** entry from **page2**, everything works as expected, *i.e.*, I get the **page1** as in the first time I left it.

The lower navbar is *glyphish* menu with three pages as well **(page_a, page_b, page_c)**. ***The problem*** happens when I go to **page_c** from **page1** and then I click the **page1** link to return back (or even when I use JQM default "back" button), the CSS of **page1** breaks displaying neither the header navbar nor the first collapsible, but rather merging the content of the first collapsible **H1** with the content of the second collapsible confusingly.

I use listview() to refresh the listviews once filling them dynamically (after each time calling pageshow()).

I had different attempts to solve the problem one of them is using page() on the disappearing collapsible item but it didn't work.

It is useful to mention that I am doing my development directly on the device Blackberry Bold 9700 (where it breaks!) on it's webkit browser; however, the functionality works well on the desktop browsers Firefox 4, Chrome and it's extension Ripple.

If anyone had such issue and managed to resolve it, I would appreciate the insight/resolution.

Cheers.

---

[EDIT] following the link provided by cpak, I added the following CSS rules to my custom css file and it managed to solve the issue.

`.ui-mobile [data-role=page], .ui-mobile [data-role=dialog],  .ui-page { height:0; overflow:hidden}`

`.ui-mobile .ui-page-active { display: block; overflow: visible; height:auto; min-height:100%;}`

Then, I removed the above rules all together and used the most recent built of JQM which resolved the issue by default. For anyone out there, I was using **v1.0a4.1** when I encountered the issue, but it seems fixed in the most recent version of JQM **(dated May 24)**

Comment: how are you using the listview() function? Code would be nice. Did you try this? $(element).listview('refresh');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had/have a similar problem when going back and forth between the #home page and other pages in Chrome and MobileSafari but not in the native Android browser.
Found this a few days back:

[Layout of home page gets screwed up in Safari and MobileSafari when using the jQuery Mobile "Back" button](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/layout-of-home-page-gets-screwed-up-in-safari-and-mobilesafari-when-using-the-jquery-mobile-back-button)

I haven't had time to try it out yet but it may be related to what you're experiencing.

[EDIT]: After re-reading your question I'm not sure this WILL help, but I'll leave the post here anyway for the community to decide =)